# Why can I no longer select data from table "groups" with MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql-8.0

Today I had to rebuild our BugZilla installation. It has been painful, mainly because I unintentionally incurred an upgrade from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.0. Now BugZilla is reporting an SQL syntax error. In an attempt to debug this, I connected directly to the database using the MySQl client and ran the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM groups;
```

This results in the error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'groups' at line 1
```

The same query works for any other table, just not "groups". I am exhausted and have no energy left to solve this. I am guessing that MySQL 8.0 introduced "GROUPS" as a keyword. I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon investigation it turns out that MySQL 8.0 has indeed introduced "groups" as a keyword, and BugZilla needs to be modified to quote the table name in all places. Unfortunately the database code is shared among many different types of database which all use different characters to quote table names.

My final solution was to switch to using PostgreSQL.